# Zonal statistics produces negative values even after changing min/max values

Tags: qgis, raster, zonal-statistics, satellite, night-time-images

I am trying to extract the values of raster images (Night light satellite images, VIIRS). I have changed the min to 0 and max to 63 through the min/max settings (User defined).

However when running "Zonal statistics", I notice that there are some negative values within the produced data. Moreover, some of the values extracted are larger than the max value I had set up earlier.

Is there a way to extract statistics based on the desired range (0 to 63).

Comment: Min-Max values are hints for rendering: map Min into 0 and Max into 255 when rendering the image. Setting does not change the data.

Comment: As noted above, you haven't actually changed the min/max values of the data, you've only changed how the data is displayed. You can use the Reclassify by Table or Raster Calculator tools to set values <0 to 0 and >63 to 63.

Comment: Oh it seems the error was on my understanding of the function of the display section. I very much appreciate the explanations given! Thank you.